# Component not being imported into app

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I'm setting up a simple React app that, by default, renders a feed of article items, but also, using `react-router`, can pull in similar lists. The problem is that I can't seem to import the components paired with the routes.

Index.html

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<!-- hard-coded header -->
<div id="react-content"></div>
<script src="bundle.js"></script> <!-- webpack js bundle -->
</body>
</html>
```

In webpack `bundle.js`:

routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory} from 'react-router';
import {Feed} from './Feed';

console.log('routes.js fired');

var App = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
      </div>
      );
  }
});

console.log(Feed);

render((
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Feed} />
  </Router>
  ), document.getElementById('react-content'));
```

Feed.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Link} from 'react-router';

var SearchBox = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    console.log('getInitialState fired');
    return {query: ''};
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
    // render - should work fine
      );
  }
});

var ItemList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var itemNodes = this.props.data.reverse().map(function(item) {
      return (
         // list rendering - works fine on its own
        );
    });
    return (
      // render
      );
  }
});

var Feed = React.createClass({
  loadItemsFromServer: function() {
    // ajax call
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    console.log('Feed fired');
    return {data: []};
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.loadItemsFromServer();
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
     // render
    );
  }
});

export default Feed; // have also tried export {Feed};
```

When I run, I get `routes.js fired` so the file is being invoked.

However, `console.log(Feed)` displays `undefined`. (When I console.log either `React` or `render` I get the expected object)

Is there something wrong with the way I'm importing/exporting or otherwise making the component available?

Comment: Leave the `default export` in feed.js and change to `import Feed from './Feed';` in routes.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{Feed} from ...` means that you export the variable `Feed` which is private in your `Feed` module. That's why you get `undefined` when you export the `Feed` variable. Because you already set `export default Feed`, so just call `Feed from ..` without the curly brackets.